# PHP Yii webservice, JSON null issue in iPhone

Tags: php, json, web-services, yii

I write web services to be consumed in iPhone with iPhone developers. My co-developers from iPhone always complain that I send data as null instead of "null".

Let me explain this scenario in detail.

```
$cdata_provider = new CSqlDataProvider("Users");

echo CJSON::encode($cdata_provider->data);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
 "users": [
 {
   "firstname":"Mike",
   "lastname":null
 },
{
   "firstname":"Steve",
   "lastname":null
 }
]
}
```

The data is OK for me. But the iphone app crashes when it receives data as null. The iphone developer says that it is great if I send "null" (with double quotes) instead of null (without double quotes.

**The required output would be:**

```
{
 "users": [
 {
   "firstname":"Mike",
   "lastname":"null"
 },
{
   "firstname":"Steve",
   "lastname":"null"
 }
]
}
```

Can I accomplish this? Do I need to configure something? I did a lot google but didn't solve this issue.

Comment: "The iphone developer says that it is great if I send "null" (with double quotes) instead of null" - your iPhone developer colleague is a prick and he doesn't want to check for `nil` or `[NSNull null]`. Tell him to not be lazy and check his damn data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str_replace()` to accomplish this

```
   echo str_replace("null",'"null"',CJSON::encode($cdata_provider->data));
```

Comment: Thanks, you are a life saver. It was not complex, however, sometimes mind stucks to think on simple things.7

Comment: It will be better if I had known the reason behind the downvotes. Downvoters feel free to edit this answer or please write your own answer, so if this is misleading,  I will delete it.

Comment: If someone's legitimate first or last name includes the word "null", you will corrupt the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the `null` with another word from the Query

```
   $cdata_provider = new CSqlDataProvider("select firstname,replace(lastname,'null','MyWord') as lastname from YourUserTable");
   echo CJSON::encode($cdata_provider->data);
```

**Output will come as**

```
      { 
        "users": 
          [
            {
              "firstname":"Mike",
              "lastname":"MyWord"
            },
            {
              "firstname":"Steve",
              "lastname":"MyWord"
            }
           ]
       }
```